# Can't understand the verse from "Cranberries - I'm Still Remembering"

Tags: lyrics

I'm having hard time to understand last 2 lines of the following verse:

> They say the cream will always rise to the top.
>   They say that good people are always first to drop.
>   **What of** Kurt Cobain, will his presence still remain?
>   Remember JFK, **ever saintly** in a way.

I higlighted the phrases which I have absolutely no idea what are they trying to convey
Would somebody be so kind and explain me their meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What of" in this case means "What would you say about Kurt Cobain?"

"Ever saintly" means "continuously a saint," "perfectly saintly, and how!"

"In a way" means "in a sense," "in some way," "in his own very personal way."

"Will his presence still remain" is just poor phraseology or very weak poetry, take your pick.